# How to add zip packages downloaded from github to anaconda

Tags: python, github, installation, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

I have download a zip package https://github.com/aburgasser/splat from github and unzip it to my local files
(I am not able to use conda install or pip install this package directly in anaconda prompt).

I tried using anaconda prompt and used  `C:\Users\20130\Desktop\SPLAT\splat-master>python setup.py install`
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "setup.py", line 15, in 
from splat.initialize import VERSION
File "C:\Users\20130\Desktop\SPLAT\splat-master\splat_*init*_.py", line 7, in 
from .core import *
File "C:\Users\20130\Desktop\SPLAT\splat-master\splat\core.py", line 15, in 
import matplotlib
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'matplotlib'

I also tried  `C:\Users\20130\Desktop\SPLAT\splat-master>pip install setup.py`
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement setup.py
ERROR: No matching distribution found for setup.py

I would like to import this package on jupyter notebook but I am not sure how to make it work.

Comment: Their `setup.py` lists Python versions up to either 2.7 or 3.5, so you likely need to create a new Conda environment with one of those versions (and `pip`) installed, then run the `pip install` with that new environment activated. It wouldn't hurt to also preinstall [their listed dependencies](https://github.com/aburgasser/splat/blob/master/setup.py#L27) using Conda prior to the `pip install`.

Comment: @merv Thanks for the comment, I created a new environment with python 3.5.5 and tried pip install setup.py. Same error occured.

Answer (score 0):

There might be an Setup file or installer when you unzipped the file. You need to install it and then import that package to your code